# Close used WinSCP session when exiting application (while in use)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winscp, winscp-net

I have an application that runs a background thread that opens a WinSCP session which is used to do stuff, like this:

```
new Thread(() => {

    //do stuff
    SessionOptions options = new SessionOptions
    {
        //options
    };

    using(Session session = new Session())
    {
        bool success = false;
        foreach (var ip in IPs)
        {
            options.HostName = ip.Value;
            try
            {
                session.Open(options);
                success = true;
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
        if(success)
        {
            CommandExecutionResult result = session.ExecuteCommand(*some command*);
            result.Check();
            someVariable = result.Output;
        }
    }

    //do stuff
})
{
    IsBackground = true
}.Start();
```

Now I noticed that if I close the app while in `using`, the thread does indeed stop but the WinSCP session remains opened (maybe because the thread is aborted?) and if I repeat the process I end up, of course, with more WinSCP sessions. How can I close the specific session I am opening in the application?

Edited: Added more of what happens in the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session.Dispose method which kills the underlying process.

Refer this documentation of WinSCP : https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_dispose

Also note the text from this article:

> If session was opened, closes it, terminates underlying WinSCP process, deletes XML log file and disposes object.
>
> As opposed to Session.Close, it’s not possible to reuse the object afterwards.

Comment: Sure, but how do I access the object? Using is supposed to dispose it anyway, but the thread is background so it is terminated by the main thread, and a catch inside it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've put your code to a C# console application and added `Thread.Sleep` to both main and background thread. If I run the application (tested on Windows 7 and 10), and close it, or even if I abruptly kill it from a task manager, WinSCP subprocess is cleanly gone.

This was expected, as the subprocess runs in the same [Windows job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) as the .NET code. So it's an operating system that takes care of cleaning WinSCP subprocess, no matter what the .NET code does. So there's something weird going on in your application.

---

Anyway, if you want to make sure that WinSCP session  is aborted, just call [`Session.Abort`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_abort) from the main thread, when you are closing the application.

Answer (score -1):

My Solution, on the Form_FormClosing event handler, just put these lines:

```
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("WinSCP"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
            (Process.GetCurrentProcess()).Kill();
```